What is the meaning of the ending of "73 Yards"?
In the episode "73 Yards" of Doctor Who, Ruby sees an  apparition of a  mysterious woman who is always 73 yards away, makes strange gestures,

and seems to be able to cause anyone to flee from Ruby in terror after talking to them.

At the end of the episode, this woman is revealed to apparently be:

 Ruby herself near the end of her life, traveling backward in time.

However, it is unclear why she would want to cause people to flee from Ruby, nor indeed how she would be capable of doing so or of travelling through time without a TARDIS or other device.
In particular, as revealed in the final episode, "The Empire of Death"

 Ruby's mother had no inherent significance, and any mysterious phenomena surrounding her—including, presumably, the snow and music—was apparently only due to gods such as Maestro and Sutekh investing her with importance.

(One's mileage may vary regarding how much this makes sense in the context of the plot). In any case, this certainly seems to suggest that Ruby does not have any supernatural powers of her own, such as those that the mysterious woman shows in "73 Yards." The episode does seem to vaguely hint at some special significance of the distance, since the perception filter of the TARDIS operates at a similar distance.
As such, what explains the ending of "73 Yards"? How and why did an elderly Ruby manage to travel back along her timeline, make everyone flee from her younger self, and possibly make the Doctor disappear?

A non-authoritative analysis: https://x.com/annastewartwho/status/1794284694558912853. Personally, I think that there is deliberately no explanation, and you're supposed to think about it yourself.

The novelisation is not out yet, but may provide an official answer.

The term "perception filter" gets thrown around both will and nilly on Doctor Who, to the point that it's almost lost all meaning. The best definition I can come up with is Douglas Adams' "Someone Else's Problem (SEP) field", which is something you assume you're not meant to worry about.

There is no explanation for it, because it never existed, as for many other things. The script has been focused on making powerful episodes, but no history or background.

I'm not a Doctor Who fan, and I've never seen the episode in the question.
That said, it appears it was the fairies who were responsible for the events in the episode "73 Yards."
From the Wikipedia entry on "73 Yards:"

"73 Yards" was written by Russell T. Davies, who described the episode as being "Welsh folk horror" and the antagonist to be the "strangest villain you'll ever see."[1] He further explained that the episode showed Ruby living "a life of penitence", required to do "something good" to earn forgiveness for the Doctor's unintentional "lack of respect" in breaking the fairy circle.[2] Gatwa stated that "73 Yards" was important to Ruby's overall development throughout the series.[3]

That quotes the author of the episode.
In a nutshell:
The Doctor breaks a fairy ring, cheesing off the fairies.  They cause him to disappear, leaving Ruby on her own.  She has to go through life on her own.  To make up for breaking the fairy circle, she must stop a politician from starting a nuclear war (read the rest of the Wikipedia article to see how.)  The last part of the fairies's "revenge" is to send Ruby back through time, becoming the mysterious "73 yard woman."  At the end of this trip through time, Ruby is back at the point where Doctor Who is about to (accidentally) break the fairy ring.  Ruby prevents it, and the whole "73 yard" timeline vanishes - it never happened.  She and Doctor Who go on to do whatever it was they were going to do on that particular cliff in Wales.

The whole thing is a time loop. Going back in time, Ruby knows that the "73 yard" woman made everyone flee from herself as the "going forward in time Ruby", so as the "going backward in time Ruby" she did what she knew had already happened.
The "going forward Ruby" used the "going backward Ruby" to stop the nuclear war by getting the "73 yard woman" close enough to the politician for her to scare him off.
The "going backward Ruby" could then recognize the proper moment from her memories and do a proper job of scaring off the politician so as to prevent the war.

Nothing (including that article) says that the woman is Ruby from the future.
